# question of structure of reverse assembled simple code

Tags: assembly, x86

I use Ubuntu 20.04  on Intel Celeron
I reverse assembled this C code.

```
extern int addintandint(int i,int j)
{
    return i + j;
}
```

like this

```
$ gcc -c addintandint.c
$ objdump -d addintandint.o > dump.txt
```

and result is this

```
addintandint.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <addintandint>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
   4:   55                      push   %rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   8:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   b:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   e:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
  11:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  14:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  16:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  17:   c3                      retq
```

I can understand by `add    %edx,%eax` we add i and j but rest of data manipulation i cannot understand.

For example,%edx and %eax I cannot follow input data stream.

and where %edx gone after add?
Someone can teach me?

Comment: Use gcc -O2 to get readable assembly output. Otherwise gcc generates such bad code that it’s hard to see what it’s doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. push stack base pointer to save the previous stack.

```
push   %rbp
```

2. set stack base pointer by stack top pointer, so it is now a frame pointer. stack initialization was finished.

```
mov    %rsp,%rbp
```

3. copy `edi` and `esi` registers to stack.  (They were set by a caller. They are the function argument variables).

```
mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
```

4. read stack that was copied by step 3. note that `eax` register is used for storing the return value of this function.

Note that this store/reload [only happens because of compiling without optimization (`-O0`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point), which is kind of a debug mode.  A normal optimized build would be much simpler.

```
mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
```

5. add operation. the result will be set in the `eax` register.

```
add    %edx,%eax
```

6. recover stack

```
pop    %rbp
```

7. jump back to caller

```
retq
```

Comment: This is the x86-64 System V ABI's calling convention.  It's not called "cdecl".  If you need a name for it, it's "sysv", as in GCC's `__attribute__((sysv_abi))` to indicate that calling convention.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thank you for your edit and comment!